# How to translate Vue output in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, vue.js, localization

I honestly think it's not possible, but I try to ask anyway. Say some real-time updated code like this:

```
<div>{{ mystring }}</div>
```

Now I need `mystring` to be translated. I don't want to do it in javascript. And I guess `_e()` and the like (wordpress i10n functions) won't work since mystring is updated on user events, after compilation. So what?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with vue or WP terminology, so I'll use tool-agnostic language*.

Well, if the translation **has** to be done on the server, [create a custom WP endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) for handling this on your server, on myString received. It will allow you to execute your server's functions.
It would accept a request with a JSON body containing your myString, and respond the same JSON format with the translated string.

So, on myString received, use [axios.post in vue](https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/#pushing-data-with-a-post-request) and assign the value of myString to the response data.

Let me know if this helped !